# query with parameters from elasticsearch (fosElasticBundle)

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm new in Symfony and i have a little problem. I been searching online, couldn't find the answer to my problem. I write search. I use fosElasticBundle. The data I store in Elasticsearch. FosElasticBundle provides a method "find()" to return records from elasticsearch. The basic functionality of this method is very simple ->find("xxx") and getting all the records with string xxx. But I want to do something more complicated.
I want to somehow get to the data stored in elasticsearch to later compare them with my parameters (geographical coordinates).
Someone knows how can I refer in "find(query)" to data from the ES?

Answer (score 0):

This is what a geo search can look like:

```php
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.blog_post');

$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

// (field, [top_left, bottom_right])
$geoQuery = new \Elastica\Query\GeoBoundingBox('geo_point', [
  '51.517577,-0.090372',
  '51.509047,-0.079461',
]);
$boolQuery->addMust($geoQuery);

$results = $finder->find($boolQuery);
```

**Source**

Talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfA9nv7Mmsw

Slides: http://foaly-nr1.github.io/slides/symfony-and-elasticsearch